# The CDF and PDF of the transformation of a random variable (absolute value)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let X~Exp(λ). Calculate and find the CDF and PDF of Y = |X-μ|.

So far my working on paper is here, but I get stuck on how to continue.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

https://s3.amazonaws.com/iedu-attachments-message/b4cce4e0d0db2b156e83fa93559bd812_a6d24999e71dce37b039ccdfd8b6c92a.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea.  In case one, write $$\mathbb{P}\{ 0 \leq X \leq y + \mu \} = \int_{0}^{y + \mu} \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = \lambda^{-2}(e^{- \lambda(y + \mu)} - 1).$$  Thus, $$F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb{P}\{Y \leq y\} = \lambda^{-2}(e^{- \lambda(y + \mu)} - 1) \quad \quad (y \geq \mu).$$  I am assuming you know how to compute the PDF from here.  I'll leave the other cases to you.

Comment: ℙ{0≤X≤y+λ}  , did you mean μ as opposed to λ?

Comment: @user3601148 There is no $\mu$ in the OP.

Comment: I edited my post accordingly.